# Higlight words in specific distance

Tags: php, regex, highlight

Hello i have this code for highlighting words in some string:

```
$keyword = 'Hello are';
$keyword = explode(' ', $keyword);

$expr = "Hello bla bla how are you today? Hello are you ....";

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($keyword); $i++) {
  $expr = preg_replace("/\w*?$keyword[$i]\w*/i", "<b>$0</b>", $expr);
}
```

It's highlighted correctly. In this case :

**Hello** bla bla how **are** you today? **Hello are** you ....

And is possible highlight keyword only in specific distance? For example in some function

```
function($keyword,$distance){
...
}
```

For example i set distance 2 and in my example will be highlighted only second sentence, because in first sentence is distance between `Hello are`, bigger than limit.

Correct result will be:
  Hello bla bla how are you today? **Hello are** you ....

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Simple, don't break the keyword let it remain **Hello are** :P

Comment: It is example i want it for example for words in sentence with different distance than 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my proposition :

```
<?php
$keywords = array('Hello', 'are');
$expr = "Hello bla bla how are you today? Hello are you ....";

echo highlight($expr, $keywords, 0), PHP_EOL;
echo highlight($expr, $keywords, 1), PHP_EOL;
echo highlight($expr, $keywords, 3), PHP_EOL;

function highlight($expression, $keywords, $distance) {
    $pattern = sprintf(
        "/
            \b(%s)\b
            ((?:\s+\w+){%s})
            \s+
            \b(%s)\b
        /ix",
        $keywords[0],
        $distance,
        $keywords[1]);
    $replacement = "<b>$1</b>$2<b>$3</b>";
    $result = preg_replace($pattern, "<b>$1</b>$2<b>$3</b>", $expression);
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$keyword = array('Hello', 'are');
$expr = "Hello bla bla how are you today? Hello are you ....";
$expr = preg_replace("/\b($keyword[0])((?:\s+\S+){3}\s+)($keyword[1])\b/i", "<b>$1</b>$2<b>$3</b>", $expr);
echo $expr,"\n";
```

**Output:**

**Hello** bla bla how **are** you today? Hello are you ....

**Source:**

```
<b>Hello</b> bla bla how <b>are</b> you today? Hello are you ....
```